# ironsource ads not loading "empty waterfall"

Tags: android, ads, ironsource

I am trying IronSource Ad network mediation with Facebook bidding. I am trying banner and interstitial ad. But I am getting this error : "Empty waterfall" every time I am trying to load the ads. Please help me out, there are no information available about this online as it's a new thing.

Comment: did you find any solution , i'm facing the same issue

Comment: I'm here to ask same thing. It doesn't show the test ads. How come test ads can be empty???

Comment: same problem for me in Unity

Comment: anybody find the answer to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question and I end up here. Finally, I managed to fix this issue.

**In the end, the reason for this issue is that Facebook is not serving ads**, and they don't serve ads if the device does not have Facebook installed or base on users' privacy settings on their platform.

In my case, I was getting that error 100% of the time despite having two AD Sources: IronSource itself and Meta.

Despite the issue with Meta, I was expecting getting at least IronSource ads.

**Issue I was facing:**

- My app was approved
- SDK was properly configured on my app
- Ads were working fine for test devices
- Ads were working fine if I enable "Test mode" for banners
- If test mode is disabled, then I got the error `606 - Empty waterfall`

**How I fixed:**

Despite the clear message (i.e. Empty waterfall), there's nothing on their platform that allows you to configure a "waterfall". After trying a lot of things, I discovered we need to create "Ad Instances" as follows:

[image: Instances Menu]

[image: Adding an Instance]

After adding an instance, I could finally get live AD's on my app.

The complete guide can be found here:

https://developers.is.com/ironsource-mobile/android/add-iron-source-instances/

Answer (score 0):

I face this issue when I test Facebook ad.

Issue was in Latest version of IronSource sdk {7.3.1} then I use old version. All problem gone.

```
implementation 'com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:7.2.7'
```

Try this :) Let me know this works for you or not.[ @MandelDuck @CihadTurhan ]